# Raspberry Pi with PiTFT+ and Processing: changing screens on tap

Tags: processing, raspberry-pi2, touchscreen

What I want to achieve is the following:

- the setup is a Raspberry Pi with a PiTFT+ touchscreen with a resolution of 480x320px; there is no mouse or physical keyboard attached, only the PiTFT+ touchscreen;
- from the tutorials I have learnt how to divide the canvas of the PiTFT+ screen in different areas so that it can contain images (e.g. icons, logos etc.. according to the needs);
- imagine the welcome screen (so-called sketch) of the PiTFT looks like this:

```java
PImage photo;
PImage photo1;
PImage logo;
void setup() {
 size(480,320);
 photo = loadImage("information.jpg");
 photo1 = loadImage("question.jpg");
 logo = loadImage("logo.png");
 fill(0, 0, 0);
 rect(0, 0, 80, 80);
 fill(50, 205, 50);
 rect(80, 0, 320, 320);
 fill(0, 0, 0);
 rect(400, 0, 480, 80);
 }
void draw() {
image(photo, 0, 0);
image(photo1, 400,0);
image(logo, 80, 0);
}
```

Once the above code is compiled the screen shows a logo in the middle and two square boxes in both top edges. Now comes the question:

- how can we make a new sketch/screen appear after the user taps the touchscreen on one of the images in the top edges - photo or photo1? The new sketch itself has an image container and two smaller images on the bottom with arrows navigation (left and right). A click on the arrows should change the image appearing on the screen.
- is such functionality possible?

My research found a lot of diverse libraries but rather for controlling external devices, e.g. LEDs or to draw specific animations. The reference section of the Processing portal reveals a lot of functions which can be used: 
https://processing.org/reference/

- here is as well one library which should allow communication with peripherals:
  the IO library
- and a library for GUI control and basic event handling system:
  the G4p GUI for processing library

Your help on this is really appreciated. Anything will be a good starting point for me to research more, assumed that the task form above is within the scope of processing.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this is to just use variables within a single sketch to show different "states" depending on those variables. Something like this:

```java
//0 is buttons, 1 is red, 2 is green
int mode = 0;

void setup() {
  size(200, 100);
}

void mousePressed() {
  if (mode == 0) {
    if (mouseX < 100) {
      mode = 1;
    } 
    else {
      mode = 2;
    }
  }
}

void draw() {
  if (mode == 0) {
    fill(255, 0, 0);
    rect(0, 0, 100, 100);
    fill(0, 255, 0);
    rect(100, 0, 100, 100);
  } 
  else if (mode == 1) {
    background(255, 0, 0);
  } 
  else if (mode == 2) {
    background(0, 255, 0);
  }
}
```

You can use a GUI library to draw the buttons and handle the click events for you, but the basic idea is the same: instead of launching a second sketch, just use variables to control the "mode" within a single sketch.

Comment: Hello Kevin! Thank for your extensive response. Let me review it and research what lies behind it and then come back to you soon. I will prepare the 4-5 screens (as separate sketches first, to get a better idea) which will in total be linked to one another and share the code here.